# Learning to use Pandas. Having trouble with .isin function

Tags: pandas, set

I am learning to code in Python and associated modules.  I am trying to utilize pandas to manipulate some data for a self generated project.

Basically I have a local spreadsheet that contains member, by First Names, Last Names, and Club affiliation.

What i want to do is create code that will check to see if new members have been added.  The problem is that I have to scrape the names from a website, which generates a spreadsheet of all members.

What i would like to happen is to take the list of names that I maintain locally, and check to see if new names have been added.

What I tried, (and failed) was to utilize pandas dataframes. I imported my local file, then imported the newly scraped listing of members both into separate panda data frames.  I cannot figure how to look at the new spreadsheet and find which items are not in the local spreadsheet. When I try in .isin function, I cant find any of the names.  I expect that this has to do with the indexing.

Would I just be better using the built in set() function?  I thought the pandas module would be handy since it is designed to manage the dataframes.

thanks, and be gentle to the newbie,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

For comparing data frames and checking for dissimilar values, you can do this.

```
(new_dataframe != old_dataframe).any(1)
```

Comment: It'll be better to first sort your dataframes on ids or some primary key, just to be sure that both the dataframes share similar ordering of rows.